# Generic function for getting different attribute in go

Tags: generics, go

I have such to code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    foo_id int
    other_id int
    one_more_id int
}

type Bar struct {
    bar_id int
}

func ids(???) []int { ??? }

func main() {   
    foos := {Foo{1},Foo{3}}
    bars := {Bar{1},Bar{3}}
    fmt.Println(ids(foos, ???)) // get foo_id
    fmt.Println(ids(foos, ???)) // get other_id
    fmt.Println(ids(foos, ???)) // get one_more_id
    fmt.Println(ids(bars, ???)) // get bar_id
}
```

I would like to make `ids` generic, to be able to pass there any structure and somehow (closure?) and attribute which I need to retrive. Is there a mean to do it? Or maybe I should use different approach?

EDIT:
My question was too ambigous, I have to clear it out:
`ids` function should be able to get more then one field from struct, depending on needs, as I updated above code.

Comment: This is solution I was looking for http://play.golang.org/p/ukbPBODP3h, thanks guys for inspirations!

Answer (score 5):

Does using an interface suit your requirements....

https://play.golang.org/p/aQiw-D4ME5

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ThingWithID interface {
    ID() int
}

type Foo struct {
    foo_id int
}

func (f Foo) ID() int {
    return f.foo_id
}

type Bar struct {
    bar_id int
}

func (b Bar) ID() int {
    return b.bar_id
}

func ids(things []ThingWithID) []int { 
    ia := []int{}
    for _,t := range things {
        ia = append(ia, t.ID())
    } 
    return ia
}

func main() {   
    foos := []ThingWithID{Foo{1}, Foo{3}}
    bars := []ThingWithID{Bar{2}, Bar{5}}
    bazs := []ThingWithID{Bar{3}, Foo{4}, Bar{6}}

    fmt.Println(ids(foos)) // get foo_id [1 3]
    fmt.Println(ids(bars)) // get bar_id [2 5]
    fmt.Println(ids(bazs)) // get bar_id, foo_id, bar_id [3 4 6]
}
```

Comment: This is an even better approach than mine. Usually whenever you are looking for something generic, you can think "how could interfaces solve this for me?"

Comment: Although I would omit the "Get" part in the method names and just call it `Id() int` as suggested in [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters)

Comment: yes that would be more idiomatic as is the use of `ID` instead of `Id` thanks to @buoto for edits.

Answer (score 2):

This would work for your case:

```
func ids(gens []interface{}) []int {
    ids := []int{}
    for _, i := range gens {
        switch foobar := i.(type) {
            case Foo:
                ids = append(ids, foobar.foo_id)
            case Bar:
                ids = append(ids, foobar.bar_id)
            default:
                continue
        }
    }
    return ids
}
```

The [Playground Link](http://play.golang.org/p/MeKPX2-GDC). I am using a [Type Switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) in this example. If you don't know which types to expect, you would need to use the [reflect package](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/). But you wouldn't have access to the unexported fields as defined in your example.

Comment: Ok, your playground code reminds me that in my closure solution I forgot to cast []Foo{} to []interface{}, thanks!